# private broadcast sender and receiver permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I recently did a code scan on my Android source code using HPFortify service. They reported security vulnerability regarding one of the broadcast receivers and sender. The broadcast sender and receiver are internal to the app and the intent is not sent outside the application. These are mainly used for internal communication. HPFortify suggested to use the broadcaster permission to reduce the attack vector. This way you are restricting broadcaster, otherwise any malicious application can send the intent and broadcast receiver will process it. Similarly they suggested to use the receiver permission so that the broadcasted intent is received by the intended receiver. This broadcaster and receiver are internal to the app and other app don't use this intent. 
Here is a my actual code for broadcaster:

```
 Intent updatedIntent = new Intent("SOME-ACTION");
 Context context = getAppContext();
 context.sendBroadcast(updatedIntent);
```

I am dynamically registering the broadcast receiver using the following code snippet.

```
this.registerReceiver(updatedReceiver,
new IntentFilter("SOME-ACTION"));
```

HPFortify suggests that the the use the `sendBroadcast` with the permission string example:

```
Intent updatedIntent = new Intent("SOME-ACTION");
Context context = getAppContext();
context.sendBroadcast(updatedIntent, "SOME-PERMISSION");
```

Similarly for Broadcast receiver:

```
this.registerReceiver(updatedReceiver,
    new IntentFilter("SOME-ACTION"),
    "SOME-PERMISSION", null);
```

I am not sure how to define this permission and use it in the broadcaster and broadcast receiver. Do I need to define the private permission in the AndroidManifest.xml and use it here?

Comment: are you using LocalBroadCastManager ? local broadcast manager prevent other application to send broadcast intent to your app. 
curtsy android developer dot com. 
" It is not possible for other applications to send these broadcasts to your app, so you don't need to worry about having security holes they can exploit."

Comment: Do I need to define any permission or can I just use this class directly?

Comment: according to me and android site :-). no need to define permission if you are using localbroadcastmanager . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html. google it for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to broadcast within application then use LocalBroadCastManager because local broadcast manager never send broadcast intent outside of the current process.

And if you want that other applications being able to receive or send your broadcasts then use BroadCastManager and you need to apply uses-permission (custom user permission ).

for more info please see below Android documentation for broadcast receiver they give detail information about security in security section.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to define the private permission in the AndroidManifest.xml and use it here?

Yes. Permissions always have to be defined in a manifest. Otherwise Android couldn't know which protection level to use for this permission.

Comment: Do I still have to use permission if I use `LocalBoadCastManager`?

Comment: @F43nd1r permission needed only if you want to send broadcasts across applications. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html specify in security section.